# Wordpress - вывести все медиа (фото, видео) из записей по постам

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Нужно сделать галерею, в которой отображаются все медиа из записей по постам. То есть должна быть галерея, в которой каждый блок выглядит так:
миниатюры картинок и видео, название\дата поста, к которому они прикреплены

желательно, чтобы это выводилось автоматически с появлением новых постов. но в крайнем случае возможен и ручной вариант добавления постов в галерею.

может быть, есть готовый плагин, может быть, готовый код. не могу найти. заранее спасибо)

Comment: Покажите свой код, что вы уже сделали и что конкретно не получается.

Comment: Код не трогал. Работаю с темой OceanWP (бесплатной версией). Посты выкладываю и редактирую стандартными средствами WP и с помощью плагина Elementor

Comment: За вас никто здесь код писать не будет. Поэтому я и начал с вопроса, а что вы сделали сами.

Comment: я понимаю. прошу подсказать, возможно, кто-то знает готовый плагин, который на это способен. меня смущает, что задача вроде ординарная и явно не мне первому понадобилась, а решение найти не могу. в WP понимаю мало, поэтому сразу извиняюсь, если вопрос глупый

Comment: Нет, я не встречал таких плагинов. Задача как раз выглядит нестандартной.